# How to save JPEGs from GIMP 2.8 and higher?

Tags: jpeg, gimp

At present I am learning GIMP 2.8 after getting the advice from this website to edit the photos captured by my Nokia N8.

The problem is: I do not know how to save them in JPEG format in GIMP because each and every time I edit them in GIMP and after that when I save them, I can't find an option to save them in JPEG format - the only option is to save them in .xcf format.

Can you please tell me how to get a JPEG version of my edited picture?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the "Export..." option on the File menu. .xcf is GIMP's native format, similar to how Photoshop uses .psd files, and stores all the information (layers and the like) GIMP needs to edit files in the future.

It's possibly worth noting this is a change from GIMP 2.6 and earlier, where the "Save..." menu option could be used to save to formats other than .xcf.

Comment: is there any way (some hidden pref ?) to force back gimp to the previous "save as" behavior ? like alot of people, I almost never need to save xcf. Now I have more click to do, and 100% of my windows now ask for confirmation before closing because "not saved" (pretending). Which mean that this requester is no longer a security but an annoyance. When manually editing dozens of images, all this is just extra pain !

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `File -> Overwrite YourImage.jpg` in Gimp 2.8.x if you are sure in what you are doing and don't need to keep the original image.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plug-in (saver) which will fix the broken save function in Gimp 2.8.x. You can find it here:

http://www.shallowsky.com/software/gimp-save/

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akkana/gimp-plugins/master/saver.py